# How to enable scala linter?

Tags: scala, sbt, lint

I added to my build.sbt as [directed](https://github.com/HairyFotr/linter):

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.14")
```

Now what?  I can compile my project as usual but don't see any output from linter.  Is there a special sbt task I need to run?

Answer (score 5):

From their [documentation](https://github.com/HairyFotr/linter):

```
terminal:
  scalac -Xplugin:<path-to-linter-jar>.jar ...

sbt: (in build.sbt)
  scalacOptions += "-Xplugin:<path-to-linter-jar>.jar"

maven: (in pom.xml inside scala-maven-plugin configuration)
  <configuration>
    <args>
      <arg>-Xplugin:<path-to-linter-jar>.jar</arg>
    </args>
  </configuration>
```

However, for me it worked by simply adding the compiler plugin as you've done. A simple way to test is to put a method like this somewhere:

```
def f(a: Int) = 10
```

You should get a warning that looks like this:

```
Parameter a is not used in method f.
[warn]   def f(a: Int) = 10
[warn]       ^
```